# Python regex named group (0 or 1 match)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse the following line Python:

```
s='SIP/200259 (In use) has taken 6 calls (last was 8932 secs ago) (order: 0)'
```

Therefore I crafted my regex:

```
sip_patt = re.compile(r'''SIP/(?P<ext>\d+).* # Extension
                          (?P<inuse>In\suse).* # Speaking
                          has\staken\s(?P<taken>\d+|no).* # Taken
                          last\swas\s(?P<last>\d+).* # Last Seen
                          order:\s(?P<order>\d+).* # Order in the queue''', re.X)
```

This yields desired result:

```
sip_patt.match(s).groups()
('200259', 'In use', '6', '8932', '0')
```

However sometimes initial string might be presented as follows (note "Not in use" in parenthesis):

```
s='SIP/200259 (Not in use) has taken 6 calls (last was 8932 secs ago) (order: 0)'
```

Hence to avoid all the "ifs" and "elses" I wanted to change my capturing logic a bit to match 0 or 1 instance of my named group "inuse", however this simply does not work. By adding "?" or {0,1} next to my named group I always get no match:

```
s='SIP/200259 (In use) has taken 6 calls (last was 8932 secs ago) (order: 0)'
sip_patt = re.compile(r'''SIP/(?P<ext>\d+).* # Extension
                          (?P<inuse>In\suse)?.* # Speaking
                          has\staken\s(?P<taken>\d+|no).* # Taken
                          last\swas\s(?P<last>\d+).* # Last Seen
                          order:\s(?P<order>\d+).* # Order in the queue''', re.X)
sip_patt.match(s).groups()
('200259', None, '6', '8932', '0')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you just match everything in (), instead of trying to find string "In\suse"? I mean something like "\(([^\)]*)\)"

Comment: For me it matters, if this exact string is present in this particular location. And if so, latter some variables will equal True, False otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What are you missing?**

The `.*` is very dangerous metasequance. It is greedy and tries to match as many as characters as possible.

That is when you write

`SIP/(?P<ext>\d+).*` the `.*` will match anything including the `(In use)` in the paranthesis. Because `(?P<inuse>In\suse)?` is an optional field and regex machine includes this in the previous `.*`

**How to correct**

You can limit what follows the `SIP digits` That is from example it is clear that `In use` begins with a `(` hence rather than matching anything with `.*` we would attempt like `[^(]` which would match anything other than a `(`. This ensures a matching only upto `(` and the `In use` is safely matched with `(?P<inuse>In\suse)?`

example:

```
>>> sip_patt = re.compile(r'''SIP/(?P<ext>\d+)[^(]* # Extension
...                           \((?P<inuse>In\suse)?\).* # Speaking
...                           has\staken\s(?P<taken>\d+|no).* # Taken
...                           last\swas\s(?P<last>\d+).* # Last Seen
...                           order:\s(?P<order>\d+).* # Order in the queue''', re.X)
>>> sip_patt.match(s).groups()
('200259', 'In use', '6', '8932', '0')
```

**NOTE** I have limited `?P<inuse>In\suse)?` within a `\( \)` so that it matches the paranthesis for safety

Comment: OK, I've learned my lesson (I assume it's not just Python specific) - _greedy_ expressions are supposed to and will _eat_ _optional_ parameters. Thank you!